# How can I calculate the number in "as large as the next #" in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table that is just a list of numbers in one column called `Standing`, ordered largest to smallest. I want to be able to calculate how many rows from the second onward the first row is equal to.

Example:

> Americas army is as large as the next 10 combined.

These are the actual results (above 50k as there are nearly 10k results total).

```
1663255
287519
238346
197905
193162
166579
134234
113571
81250
69694
67342
65702
55770
55579
54339
54328
54247
51090
```

I know how to do this programatically, I just count a loop while subtracting each value from the first until it is negative, but am having a hard time doing this in SQL.

Comment: first of all: its a very bad idea to store multiple values in one column

Comment: are they ordered by string length? what should be the result of the first line? 1+663+255?

Comment: I've updated the question to be clearer, they are one number, my system was just pretty printing the int value with commas as thousands separators. 1,663,255 = 1663255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a cumulative sum . . . for all but the first row.  This is a bit tricky in MySQL, but you can do so using variables:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*, (@sum := @sum + standing) as running_standing
      from t cross join
           (select @sum := 0) params
      where t.standing < (select max(t.standing) from t)
      order by t.standing desc
     ) tt cross join
     (select max(t.standing) as max_standing from t) as m
where tt.running_standing < m.max_standing;
```

Comment: So this gives me the `running_standing` that is the first one higher than the first value, but not the number of rows it takes to get there. I'm not after the result of `1615304` or `1671074`, but of 12.

Comment: okay, so by removing the limit and just counting the results I got what I wanted. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Side note: Do you feel this would be better done within the Python or PHP program rather than SQL?